# How would I use php-intl to convert country codes to localized country names

Tags: php, translation, icu, intl

Hello I need to retrieve full country names based on a country code and a locale in PHP. Since php-intl is now supposed to be able to do this I want to use that.

```
nl_NL
nl -> Nederland
uk -> Verenigd Koninkrijk

en_UK
nl -> The Netherlands
uk -> United Kindom
```

I *think* I need to use php-intl resource bundles somehow, but am unable to find any useful examples.

Comment: Dunno about the php-intl but you may a public resource like http://www.mega-db.com.ar/Table/iso3166

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly. The intl methods can help you with that.

You need to use [Locale::getDisplayRegion](http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplayregion.php)

Object oriented style:

```
static string Locale::getDisplayRegion ( string $locale [, string $in_locale ] )
```

Procedural style:

```
string locale_get_display_region ( string $locale [, string $in_locale ] )
```

Returns an appropriately localized display name for region of the input locale. If is NULL then the default locale is used.

So, in your case:

```
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('nl_NL', 'nl_NL');
Nederland
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('en_GB', 'nl_NL');
Verenigd Koninkrijk
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('nl_NL', 'en_GB');
Netherlands
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('en_GB', 'en_GB');
United Kingdom
```

Remember that 'GB' is used for the United Kingdom instead of 'UK'