# Is there a clean way to translate english honorific in PHP?

Tags: php, internationalization

I work on a website which handles people honorific: “Mr”, “Miss”, “Dr”…

In German, “Mister” is “Herr”. In French, it’s “Monsieur” (shortened “M.”).

Can I translate theses honorifics (short and long) in PHP the way I can translate dates or countries (e.g. intl extension)?

Comment: Eh, you mean if there is a php function that allows you to do `echo $honorific['en']` and that shows the english version?

Comment: Basically, yes. As it’s possible with [`intl` with countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515530/how-would-i-use-php-intl-to-convert-country-codes-to-localized-country-names).